# First appearance of the realistic mask effect

Tags: first-appearance, effects

What was the first movie to use the realistic mask effect - which appears to show a mask being removed that is indistinguishable from the actors face.  Was it before the Mission Impossible series?

Here is an example from Mission Impossible 2:

Comment: Reworded this to be a 'first appearance' question.  What makes you think that there was a first appearance before MI-2?

Comment: It was done at the end of MI-1; Tom Cruise wore a John Voight mask and pulled it off. But wasn't it also done in the original Mission Impossible TV series from the 1960's?

Comment: @BrettFromLA ... yes, you are correct, I'd forgotten that example from MI-1, I just remember the rather worse masks he used earlier in the same movie.  I don't think I've ever seen the original TV show - they used masks for sure, but did they create an effect as realistic as this before CGI?

Comment: They did certainly use masks in the second '88 run of the TV-show, but they didn't pull them off their faces as a complete whole rubber mask like in that example shot. They were much more elaborate and fragile, more like the ones from the later films like MI:3, I think.

Comment: On the TV show, they didn't have masks that looked like other characters, they had other characters that looked like the mask. I.e. Rollin Hand (played by Martin Landau) would wear a mask that made him look like another character ... but that other character was just Martin Landau in the mask.